# "What time" vs "At what time"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

If I want ask my classmate at what exact time did he come to class, which question is correct? I don't want to use "When".
"At what time did you come here?" 
or 
"What time did you come here?"

Comment: Why do you not want to use "when"?  "When did you get here?" would be the most natural phrasing.

Comment: I would use *arrive* or *get*, since *come* (like *go*) can refer to a duration. The two verbs I've suggested are punctiliar in nature. As for including *at* or not, it is optional.

Comment: This question would probably be better on ELL and it has  [already been asked there](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/83368/2818).

Answer (score 10):

Since the question **'What time did you come?'** gives the answer **'I came at one o'clock'**, grammatically, the preposition **'at'** should be in question form.

Thus, **'At what time...?'** is OK and from a prescriptive grammatical standpoint is correct, but most people say **'What time...?'**.

Full correct grammar:

> At what time did you come? 'I came at one (o'clock)' or 'At one (o'clock).'

Short version:

> What time did you come? 'One'.

Answer (score 2):

**"What time did you arrive at class today?**" would be clear and direct. Whether your classmate responds with a precise answer is another matter!

Answer (score 0):

So, we can say What time are you coming here? Or At what are you coming here? Both seem correct, but I would prefer the fist one.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score -1):

Without a reason of doubt the question and answer grammatically to the following are:

Ques. At what time will you come to meet me?
Ans.  I will come at 2 p.m.

One cannot answer: I will come 2 p.m. The question in this case should begin with At and the answer will and has to be  ... at 2 p.m.

Revert if a query exists.